# Is strict template evaluation in principle impossible in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I think I understand how templates are evaluated lazily in C++ e.g. a la recursive replacements and a final simplification of the expansion. This typically limits the recursion depth available. I wonder if with the features new in C++11 (e.g. variadic templates or template packs) or with some Boost it is possible to force strict template evaluation. Or is this in principle impossible in C++?

Consider for example a template which sums all integer values `0..n`:

```
template <int n>
struct sumAll { enum { value = n + sumAll<n-1>::value }; };

template <>
struct sumAll<0> { enum { value = 0 }; };

#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << sumAll<10000>::value << std::endl; }
```

Here `sumAll<10>::value` would be expanded to

```
sumAll<10>::value = 10 + sumAll<9>::value
                  = 10 + 9 + sumAll<8>::value
                  = 10 + 9 + 8 + sumAll<7>::value
                  = ...
                  = 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
```

and the final summation would only be performed once the template has been completely expanded. If that final expansion gets too long (e.g. in complex series expansions with many terms) the compiler will ultimately run out of space to store additional terms.

My question was in essence if there was a way to perform simplifications (like above summation) earlier.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by strict evaluation.

Comment: @Mat: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StrictEvaluation

Comment: Isn't template argument evaluation strict already (in the sense described by your link)? Once a template is instantiated, the template arguments are "evaluated" (in the sense that their types are determined), and only then the code of the template is considered. (The lazy aspect of templates is that the entire template  won't be compiled for a specific combination of argument types unless it is actually needed.)

Comment: Could you add an explicit example of what you mean when you say that templates are evaluated lazily, and an example of where you would want them to instead be evaluated strictly (according to your definition)? As far as I can tell, templates *are* evaluated strictly, because the arguments to templates are instantiated before the templates themselves are.

Comment: @Mankarse: I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Is the above summation definitely a "simplification"? The standard doesn't require that the compiler "forgets" about the types `sumAll<0> ... sumAll<9>` once it has computed `sumAll<10>::value`, and I don't know whether or not implementations do forget types once instantiated. If every meta-function is (in effect) memoized, then you don't save any space by dictating that it be performed earlier, although you might affect which template finally triggers the out of memory error.

Comment: @SteveJessop, that's a good point, since all `sumAll` are types. Maybe there's the answer somewhere.

Comment: Maybe someone could suggest ways to improve this so it becomes a valid question. I think this question has a right answer and is directly related to a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You decide the recursion depth yourself. And just like normal recursion can cause stack overflows, template recursion can. But that's often fixable by a better recursive algorithm. Trivially:

```
template <int n>
struct sumAll { enum { value = n + n-1 + sumAll<n-2>::value }; };

template <>
struct sumAll<1> { enum { value = 0 }; };

template <>
struct sumAll<0> { enum { value = 0 }; };
```

Smarter:

```
template <int n>
struct sumAll { enum { value = (n*n+2)/2; };
```

Of course, you may complain that the latter is just being silly and real examples are more complex. But isn't that the whole problem? The compiler can't magically make that complexity go away for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We can write ordinary functions in a tail-recursive way so that the required stack space becomes independent of the recursion depth. In the example I gave this seemed to be impossible with templates (but I am not sure if that's correct lingo there). And of course I am not really interested in this specific example, more the general limitations of TMP.

Comment: @honk: Templates don't really work like recursions, since you don't actually *recurse*, but invoke a completely new meta-function. Thanks to partial and explicit specialization, it's hard for the compiler to see if all "recursive" invocations actually expand the same terms. Note that with C++11's `constexpr` functions, you can get truly recursive (and tail-call optimizable) meta-functions for compile-time and runtime values.

Comment: Also, your trivial version puts the same number of terms on the template "stack", so it doesn't help at all. A TMP algorithm which requires `N` steps will (at least AFAICT) always require `N` terms to be remembered.

Comment: @Xeo: Actually, that's not entirely true. When evaluating `sumAll<10000>::value`, the compiler already checked all specializations. But you're hitting the halting problem if you want to prove that the evaluation of `sum<n>::value` halts.

Comment: @honk: No, it doesn't. `sumAll<9999>` is NOT on the template stack.

Comment: @honk: The simplified version does not invoke any other meta-function, so there are not "`N` steps". It just uses a known "algorithm" to calculate the sum.

Comment: @Xeo, sure, but my question wasn't if one can find a better algorithm for a silly problem, but if template expansion can be made more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

C++ templates are turing-complete, which means that you use them to evaluate *every* computable function at compile time. It then follows from the halting theorem that

1. You cannot, in general, compute the amount of memory require to compile of a C++ program in advance.  (I.e., there is no *computable* function which maps every C++ program to a memory bound for its compilation)
2. You cannot, in general, decide whether the compiler will ever finish instantiating template, or will go on forever.

So while you might be able to tweak a compiler to use less memory in *some* cases, you cannot solve the general problem of it running out of memory sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the problem you are describing (that's what in some way motivated this question), but I was more interested if there was another way of evaluating templates. Can you connect what you are saying to that or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: @honk Hm, I think I missread your question. I assumed you wanted to know whether the *compiler* could evaluate earlier to conserve memory, and thus argues that even if it did, you'd still need unbounded memory in some cases. Now that I re-read your question I realize that you actually simply want to know if recursions can be expression more efficiently in C++11 than they can be in C++03. Sorry for the confusion...